# Como definir la métrica de si es meses o días en rangeBetween

Tags: python, pyspark

Tengo una base con variables contrato, fecha y marca. La fecha está en valores yyyy-MM--dd y la marca son 0 o 1. Quiero usar la funcion RangeBetween para que, dada la fecha de cada observacion, revise si en los próximos 12 meses o 365 dias existe una marca 1 o todos son 0.

Tengo este código pero no me genera el resultado correcto pues se fija mas allá de 12 meses, supongo es porque en algún lugar le tengo que decir si son 12 meses, 12 días,  o cual es la métrica que quiero.

```
ventana = Window.partitionBy('contrato').orderBy(col("data_date1").cast("date")).rangeBetween(1,365)
ventana_m = Window.partitionBy('contrato').orderBy(col("data_date1").cast("date")).rangeBetween(1,12)
contratos2 = contratos.select('*',
                              F.max("marca_bf").over(ventana).alias("inc_12m"),
                              F.max("marca_bf").over(ventana_m).alias("inc_12m_2")
                             )
contratos2.show()
```

estoy haciendo ambas pruebas, 12 indicando 12 meses o 365 indicando días. Ambas me salen mal

Alguna idea??